# How to use chessbase to find moves that produce "only winning sequences" if present?

Tags: opening, stockfish, chessbase, calculation

A lot of times you may find yourself in a losing position, and with best play surely, you'll stay losing, but there is a possibility that you make a move which is not necessarily considered the best move according to the engine, but the response from the opponent turns out to be an "only winning line" or perhaps two.

Is there a feature in that program or any other program to find such moves?